# So many contact deletes

Tags: android

I tried to manages my contacts using a pc application, from this app I deleted a lot of unused contact. 
When the application try to update the phone list it throw a notification with this message "So many contact deletes".
This notification comes up every 3 or 4 hours, it is annoying now. I have to force app to close to remove it.
Anyone has an idea of what can I do to stop this notification?

Comment: Not programming related may fit for http://android.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Follow these steps

1. Make sure your contacts are still in your `Google account`.  You can
   see this by visiting http://www.google.com/contacts
2. On your Android phone `> Go into Setting > Applications > Manage Applications > Contacts Storage`
3. Inside contacts storage choose: `Clear Data`.

That’s all what you need to do.

Next time your phone tries to sync with Google it will repopulate your contacts with no annoying error message.